# knockout multiple viewmodels in a page not working

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

i have two seperate viewmodels in a page

```
function AModel() {
...
}
function BModel() {
...
self.testValue= ko.observable('test')
}

 $(document).ready(function() {
var AModel1= new AModel();
var BModel1= new BModel();
ko.applyBindings(AModel1);
ko.applyBindings(BModel1);
});
```

now in html page
how do i make it work?

```
<span data-bind="text: BModel1.testValue" ></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `ko.applyBindings` multiple times on the same DOM element, this can lead to problems or to an exceptions since KO 2.3.

What you can do is to create one "wrapper" viewmodel and call `ko.applyBindings` with it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var AModel1= new AModel();
    var BModel1= new BModel();
    ko.applyBindings({ AModel1: AModel1, BModel1: BModel1 });
});
```

Then you can use your view:

```
<span data-bind="text: BModel1.testValue" ></span>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ahck/).